# Why is the copy constructor not trivial just because there is a user defined destructor?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, template-meta-programming, type-traits

The following excerpt compiles in Clang-libstdc++ or Clang-libc++, GCC, many of their versions and all three versions of the language since 11 (14 & 17):

```
#include <type_traits>

struct HasUserDefinedDestructor {
    ~HasUserDefinedDestructor() {}
};

using HUDD = HasUserDefinedDestructor;

static_assert(not std::is_trivially_move_constructible<HUDD>::value, "");
static_assert(not std::is_trivially_copy_constructible<HUDD>::value, "");
```

This surprises me, since a copy only requires trivial operations.

Is this an error in the compilers/libraries or does the standard say somewhere that having a user defined destructor makes the copy and move constructors not trivial?

**Edit: Why this is not a repeat of default construction question:**
Given the comments we know "noexceptness" and triviality of constructors are affected by the noexceptness and triviality of the destructor, but before knowing that all of these traits are related the questions are different.  Having this question allows anybody to see this is related

Comment: You'll get different results if you would use `= default` for your destructor.

Comment: https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2827

Comment: "*Having this question allows anybody to see this is related*" The question will still be here if it's a duplicate. It will simply point to another question, which shows that they are related.

Answer (score 1):

`is_trivially_constructible` is [defined as follows](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/meta.unary.prop#lib:is_trivially_constructible) (bold is mine):

> `is_­constructible_­v<T,Args...>` is `true` and the variable definition for `is_­constructible`, as defined below, **is known to call no operation that is not trivial**

«Defined below» is [[meta.unary.op]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/meta.unary.prop#8):

> The predicate condition for a template specialization `is_­constructible<T, Args...>` shall be satisfied if and only if the following variable definition would be well-formed for some invented variable `t`:
>
> `T t(declval<Args>()...);`

So yes, `is_trivially_[copy|move]_constructible_v` is `false` when the destructor is not trivial.

Comment: That is the definition of a variable `t`, `t` is not being destroyed.  The semicolon makes a difference: it is not a temporary expression that creates and destroys a `T`, it just *creates* a variable `t` that is not destroyed there.

Comment: @TheCppZoo https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2827

Comment: Because of that last link (excellent find), we can conclude that these implementations are broken because what they consider is not `S t();` but `S{}`, an expression that creates and destroys.

Comment: @TheCppZoo I'd say it is an issue in the wording. It should say that the variable definition known not to cause calls to operation that is not trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Per [[dcl.fct.def.default]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct.def.default#5):

> [...] A function is user-provided if it is user-declared and not explicitly
>   defaulted or deleted on its first declaration. [...]

Therefore, given

```
struct HasUserDefinedDestructor {
    ~HasUserDefinedDestructor() {}
};
```

`HasUserDefinedDestructor` has a user-provided destructor.

Per [[class.dtor]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.dtor#6):

> A destructor is trivial if it is not user-provided and if: [...]
>
> Otherwise, the destructor is *non-trivial*.

Therefore, `HasUserDefinedDestructor` has a *non-trivial* destructor.

Per [[meta.unary.prop]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/meta.unary.prop#tab:type-traits.properties):

> ```
> template <class T, class... Args>
> struct is_­trivially_constructible;
> ```
>
> *Condition:* `is_­constructible_­v<T, Args...>` is `true` and the variable definition for `is_­constructible`, as defined below, **is
>   known to call no operation that is not trivial** ([basic.types],
>   [special]).
>
> *Pre-condition:* `T` and all types in the parameter pack `Args` shall be a complete type, *cv* `void`, or an array of unknown bound.
>
> ```
> template <class T>
> struct is_­trivially_copy_­constructible;
> ```
>
> *Condition:* For a referenceable type `T`, the same result as `is_­trivially_­constructible_­v<T, const T&>`, otherwise `false`.
>
> *Pre-condition:* `T` shall be a complete type, *cv* `void`, or an array of unknown bound.
>
> ```
> template <class T>
> struct is_­trivially_­move_­constructible;
> ```
>
> *Condition:* For a referenceable type `T`, the same result as `is_­trivially_­constructible_­v<T, T&&>`, otherwise `false`.
>
> *Pre-condition:* `T` shall be a complete type, *cv* `void`, or an array of unknown bound.

Per [[meta.unary.prop]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/meta.unary.prop#tab:type-traits.properties#8):

> The predicate condition for a template specialization
>   `is_­constructible<T, Args...>` shall be satisfied if and only if the
>   following variable definition would be well-formed for some invented
>   variable `t`:
>
> ```
> T t(declval<Args>()...);
> ```
>
> [ *Note:* These tokens are never interpreted as a function
>   declaration. — *end note* ] Access checking is performed as if
>   in a context unrelated to `T` and any of the `Args`. Only the validity
>   of the immediate context of the variable initialization is considered.
>   [ *Note:* The evaluation of the initialization can result in side
>   effects such as the instantiation of class template specializations
>   and function template specializations, the generation of
>   implicitly-defined functions, and so on. Such side effects are not in
>   the “immediate context” and can result in the program being
>   ill-formed. — *end note* ]

The variable definition is supposed to "call" the destructor even though it seems that the destructor is not called at the place of the defintion. Therefore, `std::is_trivially_move_constructible<HUDD>::value` is `false`, as is `std::is_trivially_copy_constructible<HUDD>::value`.

Comment: There does not seem to be a relation between the variable definition `t` and the destructor.  No destructor gets executed in the `T t(declval<const T &>())`, so, what is the non-trivial operation that drives the move, copy constructors non-trivial?

Comment: @TheCppZoo A variable definition is supposed to "call" the destructor.

Comment: That is the definition of a variable `t`, in a statement (there is a semicolon), the destructor of `t` is not called in that statement.  That is the statement used to specify what are the operations involved to decide triviality, so, your answer is simply not a reason

Comment: @TheCppZoo _That variable definition results in a call to the S destructor._ https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2827

Comment: @Peter The destructor can only be called if the constructor succeeded. In `T t(declval<Args>()...);` if `T` constructor throws no `T` destructor is called, if the constructor succeeds, no destructor is called either.

Comment: @TheCppZoo Apparently you are confused here. That's because this is a bit of confusing. The variable definition is considered to be responsible call to the destructor even though the call does not appear to happen at the place of the variable definition.

Comment: @Peter _And what if a T is a member of a class/struct_ It is not a variable definition then.

Comment: @Peter If `T` is a member of `T` than `sizeof(T)` is infinite because each `T` must have a unique address.